# Call Python code from an existing project written in Swift

Tags: python, swift

I need a way to call Python code from Swift on an Apple platform. A library would be ideal. I've done a considerable amount of Google searching, and the closest material I found is for Objective-C.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow apps to be written, in any part, in languages besides Obj-C and Swift. You're not likely to find any luck in this endeavour (and even if you find a hacky solution, it wouldn't be allowed on the App Store).

Comment: In the deleted answer (seriously, we're deleting answers now that contain a helpful link to an article?), there's a helpful link for OS X at least: http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/25/how-to-execute-shell-commands-from-swift/

Comment: @oxguy3 i don't think that' necessarily true. Checkout this doc from apple -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone is ever interested in calling python from swift, here is some helpful material I found:

- U the python framework - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html
- PyObjC (a little more challenging) -
- Cobbal - https://github.com/cobbal/python-for-iphone
- Python docs (you would need to make C-Swift bridge)

Most of it is for Objective-c, but if you need to use swift you can easily just create an ObjC-Swift bridge (super-super easy) - Lookup the apple docs

Comment: @frogcjn - They mention how to use other versions in the Apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2328/_index.html)

Comment: @TommieC. since Python 3 framework is not embed in System Library, I've tried, not that easy. The document still only works on Python 2.7. It means Xcode 5.0 is the new version not Python 3.

Answer (score 17):

In swift 5 you can try [PythonKit](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit) framework.

Here's example of the usage:

```
import PythonKit

let sys = try Python.import("sys")

print("Python \(sys.version_info.major).\(sys.version_info.minor)")
print("Python Version: \(sys.version)")
print("Python Encoding: \(sys.getdefaultencoding().upper())")
```

Comment: I've been trying to load a custom module with PythonKit but can't seem to do it. Do you have any idea how (or if) that's supposed to work? I'm able to use `os.chdir()` and `os.getcwd()` to get to the directory where my module is installed, but it fails loading the actual module.

Comment: I realized I can add a custom directory to PYTHONPATH using `sys.path.append()`, but I still can't load my custom module. I can load it from the terminal, so the module should be fine.

Answer (score 11):

I found this excellent and up to date gist that walks you through a complete solution: https://github.com/ndevenish/Site-ndevenish/blob/master/_posts/2017-04-11-using-python-with-swift-3.markdown

If you can get away with just using NSTask to launch a Python process, that's a pretty good option too.

Comment: Is there any way to use this in iOS project? It seems the given link described the steps to use it in macOS.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 4.2 there was an approved feature to allow dynamic languages to be ported directly into swift

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0195-dynamic-member-lookup.md

Will look similar to:

```
  // import pickle
  let pickle = Python.import("pickle")

  // file = open(filename)
  let file = Python.open(filename)

  // blob = file.read()
  let blob = file.read()

  // result = pickle.loads(blob)
  let result = pickle.loads(blob)
```

Comment: does it only works in Playground? 'cuz I really need it in the Xcode iOS project but it doesn't know what is Python..

Comment: @SerhiiPalash Swift is Swift, whether used in Playground or compiled for a distributable binary.