# Import Python code and library in Swift

Tags: python, swift, macos

I want write a Skype application for OS X in Swift, but that application needs the skype4com library. I find that library in Python, which works on OS X.

Is it possible to import Python code into Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best bet is probably going to be the python framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html

Also check this out, very similar to your question: [How to call Python code from an existing iOS project written in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/how-to-call-python-code-from-an-existing-ios-project-written-in-swift)