# swift playground error: module 'Python' has no member named 'import'

Tags: python, swift, numpy

I'm new to Swift and looking into it's data science capabilities.

I've created a simple `.playground` file and decided to import a numpy module from python:

```
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: hellow_world.playground:5:10: error: module 'Python' has no member named 'import'
```

The same happens if I run it in the command line. Both python 2 and python 3  with numpy are installed in my system (OS X). What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

- Mac OS X version: 10.13.6
- Swift toolchain version: 4.1.3

Comment: I'd recommend following a tutorial like: https://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/swift-python/swift-and-python-interop-using-dynamic-member-lookup

Comment: Import python doesn't imply importing numpy, also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/call-python-code-from-an-existing-project-written-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you for these links! 

My problem is that I can't even import any package, `module 'Python' has no member named 'import' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to check.

1. Presumably you're using the swift / tensorflow toolchain from latest download link here (and you've configured Xcode to use it. 
   View Xcode’s (Preferences,  Components > Toolchains, and select the installed Swift for TensorFlow toolchain.)
   https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md
2. Make sure you change the Xcode build system to legacy (File > Project Settings > Build System).
3. Check the runtime search path 
   /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest/usr/lib/swift/macosx

**UPDATE:**
Have a look at XcodeGen which can automagically create an xcode project with relevant settings for swift for tensorflow.
I crafted a [project.yml](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/pull/92) file here

**DO NOT** include libppython2.7.tbd  in the linked frameworks. tensorflow will automagically find relevant python version 3 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually the first step was enough for me to run it without errors

Comment: I've been experimenting with bunch of python frameworks here - https://github.com/johndpope/swiftReinforce

Comment: I don't see libpython ... for #3, I added that exact path. In that path, I see a hopeful-looking "libswiftPython.dylib" but that's it