# I can't use Python module in Swift

Tags: python, swift, macos, swift-playground

I tried the following codes in a playground file.

```
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
```

And then, I got the following error.

> Module 'Python' has no member named 'import'

I applied the following solutions to this execution.

- [swift playground error: module 'Python' has no member named 'import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605277/swift-playground-error-module-python-has-no-member-named-import/52223502)
- [Call Python code from an existing project written in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/call-python-code-from-an-existing-project-written-in-swift)

Exceptionally, I can't find out 'runtime search path', so I don't apply the solution in relation to it.
But as the solutions' question, I shoud be able to run this code without entering something in runtime search path.
This problem also occur in command line version.
It is so mysterious that I wonder the story, "You can use Python in Swift!" is a fake of April fools.

Please help me from the illusion!

Xcode: 10.1
Swift: 4.2.1

Comment: It should work already if you have set XCode's Toolchains to Swift for TensorFlow (make sure you use the latest snapshot) and make sure you restart XCode after setting a new Toolchain.

Comment: how did you get `import Python` to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year later, I got a solution.
The name of module was wrong.

```swift
import PythonKit
let np = Python.import("numpy")
```

I should have installed on [this way](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md) and implemented [this way](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/model_training_walkthrough) exactly.

Thanks regards!

Xcode: 11.3.1
Swift: 4.2
Toolchain: Swift for TensorFlow 0.8 Release

Comment: For a little context on this, we originally used `import Python` within the Swift for TensorFlow toolchain, but it created a naming conflict. Outside of the Swift for TensorFlow toolchain, PythonKit was the module that provided this functionality. As of our 0.8 release, we switched to using `import PythonKit` to be consistent in this usage. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @BradLarson the problem is that now this needs to be updated to all the documentation (including Swift's project), where the old `import Python` is being used.

Comment: @wizofe - Outside of the Swift for TensorFlow project, PythonKit should have been the means that Python functionality was obtained. We've been gradually transitioning our notebooks over by using `#if canImport(PythonKit)`, with a fallback to the old Python naming. We'll soon be removing the old Python module references, now that people have had enough time to move over.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson! I had the same problem as this post, while I was going through some examples from the Swift for TensorFlow project! In any case it’s a very exciting one, so keep up the good work +1