# How to setup swift project in a terminal to enable python

Tags: python, swift

I'm new to swift and would like to learn its integration with Python. I saw fast ai course on swift and they use Python libs from it. My question is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605277/swift-playground-error-module-python-has-no-member-named-import) where I want to run simple example like this one:

```
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
```

and I'm getting this error

```
error: module 'Python' has no member named 'import'
public let np = Python.import("numpy")
                ^~~~~~ ~~~~~~
```

The solution proposed in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605277/swift-playground-error-module-python-has-no-member-named-import) is to setup properly XCode to look-up proper python lib. My question is how to do it without XCode (I often work remotely on nodes via ssh and I want to learn how to do everything in terminal using shell/vim).

Could someone outline a recipe how to setu project from command line such that it will enable Python for swift.

Thanks,
Valentin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the procedure is rather trivial. Here are the steps I did on macOS:

1. Download Tensforflow swift toolchain, it will install new swift toolchain into /Library/Developer/Toolchains
2. setup environment

   ```
   export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest/usr/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Create new package

   ```
   swift package init --type executable
   ```
4. Adjust created Package.swift file to have this section (replace MyCde with whatever your package/dir name is:

   ```
   let package = Package(
       name: "MyCode",
       platforms: [
          .macOS(.v10_15),
       ], ....
   ```

The latter changes requires to enable support for Python in TF (my understanding the macOS should be above 10.13).

After that I was able to compile my package as simple as

```
swift build
```