# Objective C or Swift implementation of Python's SciPy interpolate.rbf function

Tags: python, objective-c, swift, math, scipy

Is there any implementation of radial basis function approximation/interpolation of n-dimensional scattered data like Python's SciPy provides [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) in Swift or Objective C (objective c is better)? I need to integrate in one of iOS application but can't find any source or something similar to that, even if there is a C implementation, I will be happy to use that.

I have spent hours to figure out one but can't find any close match of SciPy or RBF in Objective C or swift. I was able to find Python Numpy close match implementation in using [swix](https://stsievert.com/swix) but nothing for SciPy.

Thanks for reading and help.

Comment: Why not calling the Python function instead? https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/PythonInteroperability.md

Comment: Ohh I was not aware of that (my bad). Let me check, looks like numpy is available easily so i feel should SciPY too.

Comment: @Cristik, that solution you suggested is using TensorFlow with Swift and I need to embed that in iOS app store app with python support so I am not sure that will work. I tried to use Python.import but did not work.

Comment: Check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/call-python-code-from-an-existing-project-written-in-swift

Comment: I think that uses Python.framework and only available on macOS not iOS, at least i can't find any example or usage and tried myself with xcode too.