# XCode or Visual Studio ? Building Human Motion detection iOS app using iPhone camera

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, visual-studio

I am a Bioengineer and need to build a Motion Capture Validation app on my iPhone 8.  My goal is have my app capture the motion of a human's full body and analyse it to confirm if the person performed well the movement it should have done or not. The app flow is very simple: just have a “Welcome” page and then go onto the Exercise page, where the person will have its mouvement recorded. Mouvements are in 2D and very simple: for example, front-facing human raising straight leg to the side by 45 degrees.

To build the app for iOS, I know the only way is to code it in Swift, so I am considering using XCode to do so. However, my Motion Capture Analysis section will likely be in Python. If I understand correctly, XCode does not go well with Python. Is there a way to make XCode 11 working for Python? Or should I use Visual Studio Code?

How my motion capture analysis will work: 
1. My app will have access to the camera of my iPhone (I do not care which one, does not matter). 
2. The app will not record a video but take pictures (3 per second at least) from the camera's visual.
3. The image will be called by my Python code.
4. The code will transform it into a skeletal model. 
5. The skeletal model obtained will be compared to a "good mouvement" skeletal model.
6. The python code will send a Yes/No validation message to the app.
5. The app will display a green tick to say the mouvement was well performed, and a red cross if not.

So, as you can see, when my app runs, it will be asking the Swift code (skeleton of my app) and the Python code (motion analysis of the person in the camera) to run together. A Python file will call the images from the “App”.  And the Swift code will call my Python code to get a YES/NO answer. I do not know if that is something I can do in XCode?

Could you help me?

Best regards,

H.R.

Comment: Here's some info for MacOS, I'm not sure about iOS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/call-python-code-from-an-existing-project-written-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to call python code using NSTask in swift for macOS projects. I am not sure in iOS, you can try using `PythonKit`

```
#if canImport(PythonKit)
    import PythonKit
#else
    import Python
#endif
print(Python.version)
```

By default, when you import Python, Swift searches system library paths for the newest version of Python installed. To use a specific Python installation, set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable to the libpython shared library provided by the installation.
You can use like below-

```
let pythonInt: PythonObject = 1
```

In Swift, PythonObject represents an object from Python. All Python APIs use and return PythonObject instances.

Basic types in Swift (like numbers and arrays) are convertible to PythonObject. In some cases (for literals and functions taking PythonConvertible arguments), conversion happens implicitly. To explicitly cast a Swift value to PythonObject, use the PythonObject initializer.