# Swift receive string and run it in Python

Tags: python, swift

Is there a way to get a string from a user and convert it into a python code?

```
 let pyString = """

     start = 'hello'
     end = 'world'
     print(start + ' ' + end)

 """

 func py(input: String) {
 //  run input as python

 }

 py(input: pyString)
 // output: "Hello world"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Python code from an existing project written in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927604/call-python-code-from-an-existing-project-written-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to do that .
You can invoke the system interpreter `subprocess.run(...)` with option `-c` and pass the commands as string.

You can also save the string to a file and execute it with the system interpreter.